# iOS 6 Facebook not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using this code:

```
_accountStore = [ACAccountStore new];

    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount =
    [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
     ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSArray *accounts =
    [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:
     facebookTypeAccount];

    _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                           options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey:myKey, ACFacebookPermissionsKey:@[@""]}
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if(granted)
                                            {
                                                NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                                _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                                NSLog(@"Success");

                                                [self parseUserDataWithCompletion:completion];
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

                                                [self parseUserDataWithCompletion:completion];
                                            }
                                        }];
```

works just fine on the device. But running on the simulator gives the error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)"
```

UPDATE:
It is not working on the device either.

It used to work. But now not anymore... What happend? Did fb change something?

Comment: Thats a user denied permissions error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that:

```
ACFacebookPermissionsKey:@[@""]
```

had to be changed to

```
ACFacebookPermissionsKey:@[]
```